# Subtraction of colours - Need to get the transparent value of a colour

Tags: css, transparency, alpha

I was just trying to get the rgba value of a rgb-colour (#ebfcff).
The rgb-colour is the rgba when put on a white background. (a stands for alpha)

So:
searchedColour + #ffffff = #ebfcff

In my assessment the solution would be to subtract white from #ebfcff.
But how do you subtract colours ?

I already searched for an adequate solution.
Does anyone know how to subtract white from a given RGB-Colour to get a new colour, which is in rgba-format, that equals the given colour when it gets overlapped with white ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert RGB-->RGBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-rgba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Colour values aren't just added.

When you plot a colour `X` on top of a colour `Y`, the value of each colour channel of the resulting colour, `C`, is given by:

```
C = X * a + Y * (1-a)
```

using the floating point representation (each channel is a value from 0 to 1); where `a` is the alpha channel of `X`. (It's easily converted back to 0-255).

On a white background, `Y` is 1 for all channels, so:

```
C = X * a + (1-a)
```

So, if `a` is 0, you clearly can't find X, which makes sense: If the colour was totally transparent, it makes no difference to the combined colour.

Similarly, if your colour was white (`X`=1) (on a white background), you couldn't determine the alpha (the combined colour would be white regardless of the alpha).

Also, you can't find either `X` or `a` without knowing the other.

If you knew the alpha of the colour (`a`), then you could determine what the colour (`X`) was, but if your combined colour (`C`) is a discrete value (such as an integer from 0 to 255), then it is rounded, so you can only get an approximation of the plotted colour (`X`). How accurate it is depends on the alpha (the more transparent the plotted colour was, the less accurately you can determine the colour).

So, solving for X (where the background (`Y`) is white):

```
            X * a = C + a - 1
Therefore:  X = (C + a - 1 ) / a
```

For 8-bit colour channels (24-bit colour):

```
X = 255 * ( C/255 + a/255 - 1 ) / (a/255)
```

(Given a 6-digit hexadecimal value, apply this for each pair of digits, `C`).

You could optimise it to avoid the floating point calculation.

I don't know if that's any use, but that's all you can do.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ```(1-a)```, else ```C = X * a + Y * (a-1)``` would give negative values in some cases (a<0.5)

Comment: @FrankM You're right! I've corrected the answer. Thanks.