# Finding "equivalent" color with opacity

Tags: css, colors

Say I have a background color with a "ribbon" running over it in another solid color. Now, I want the ribbon to be partially transparent to let some details blend through, but still keep the ribbon the "same color" over the background.

Is there a way to (easily) determine, for a given opacity/alpha < 100% of the ribbon color, what RGB values it should have to be identical to its color with 100% opacity over the background?

Here's a picture. Background is `rgb(72, 28, 97)`, ribbon `rgb(45, 34, 70)`. I want a `rgba(r, g, b, a)` for the ribbon so that it appears identical to this solid color.

[image]

Comment: A very similar question can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-rgba but the key difference is that that question specifies a base color of white, while this one is arbitrary.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Color blending is just a linear interpolation per channel, right? So the math is pretty simple. If you have RGBA1 over RGB2, the effective visual result RGB3 will be:

```
r3 = r2 + (r1-r2)*a1
g3 = g2 + (g1-g2)*a1
b3 = b2 + (b1-b2)*a1
```

…where the alpha channel is from 0.0 to 1.0.

*Sanity check: if the alpha is 0, is RGB3 the same as RGB2? Yes. If the alpha is 1, is RGB3 the same as RGB1? Yes.*

If you locked down only the background color and final color, there are a large number of RGBA colors (infinite, in floating-point space) that could satisfy the requirements. So you have to pick either the color of the bar or the opacity level you want, and find out the value of the other.

### Picking the Color Based on Alpha

If you know RGB3 (the final desired color), RGB2 (the background color), and A1 (how much opacity you want), and you are just looking for RGB1, then we can re-arrange the equations thusly:

```
r1 = (r3 - r2 + r2*a1)/a1
g1 = (g3 - g2 + g2*a1)/a1
b1 = (b3 - b2 + b2*a1)/a1
```

*There are some color combinations which are theoretically possible, but impossible given the standard RGBA range. For example, if the background is pure black, the desired perceived color is pure white, and the desired alpha is 1%, then you would need:*

```
r1 = g1 = b1 = 255/0.01 = 25500
```

*…a super-bright white 100× brighter than any available.*

### Picking the Alpha Based on Colors

If you know RGB3 (the final desired color), RGB2 (the background color), and RGB1 (the color you have that you want to vary the opacity of), and you are just looking for A1, then we can re-arrange the equations thusly:

```
a1 = (r3-r2) / (r1-r2)
a1 = (g3-g2) / (g1-g2)
a1 = (b3-b2) / (b1-b2)
```

*If these give different values, then you can't make it match exactly, but you can average the alphas to get as close as possible. For example, there's no opacity in the world that will let you put green over red to get blue.*

Comment: Aren't `r1`, `g1`, and `b1` also unknown?

Comment: @Eric I'm not certain. I've edited the answer in case it is the alpha level that is known and the colors that are not.

Comment: Heads up, I used your first three formulas in Photoshop to find what a color would be at 0.8 alpha when my only other reference color was white... I had to use 1 + (1 - a) or 1.2 in order to find the right color...

Comment: @Phrogz I'm using your 'Pick the Color Based on Alpha' equations, and I get a negative number (-31) for the red channel. When I use the negative as the red value, I get the same result as if I had used 0 as the red value. Is there a way to convert this negative into something useable? Any clue as to what's going on here?

Comment: Maybe my calculations are off, but this formula produces unexpected result when RGB3 = #163920, RGB2 = #FFFFFF, and A1 = 0.92; the calculated RGB1 = rgb(2, 40, 13), but rgba(2, 40, 13, 0.92) = #15381F, not #163920.

Answer (score 14):

i made a LESS mixin using Phrogz' answer. you input:

1. how the colour should look
2. with a certain alpha
3. on a given background (default being white)

Here's the code:

```
.bg_alpha_calc (@desired_colour, @desired_alpha, @background_colour: white) {
    @r3: red(@desired_colour);
    @g3: green(@desired_colour);
    @b3: blue(@desired_colour);

    @r2: red(@background_colour);
    @g2: green(@background_colour);
    @b2: blue(@background_colour);

    // r1 = (r3 - r2 + r2 * a1) / a1
    @r1: ( @r3 - @r2 + (@r2 * @desired_alpha) ) / @desired_alpha;
    @g1: ( @g3 - @g2 + (@g2 * @desired_alpha) ) / @desired_alpha;
    @b1: ( @b3 - @b2 + (@b2 * @desired_alpha) ) / @desired_alpha;

    background-color: @desired_colour;
    background-color: rgba(@r1, @g1, @b1, @desired_alpha);

}
```

Usage like so:

```
@mycolour: #abc;
@another_colour: blue;
.box_overlay {
  // example:
  .bg_alpha_calc (@mycolour, 0.97, @another_colour);
  // or (for white bg) just:
  .bg_alpha_calc (@mycolour, 0.97);
}
```

Obviously doesn't work for impossible combinations (as mentioned by Phrogz), that means only mild levels of transparency are supported. See how you go with it.

Comment: @mixin bg_alpha_calc ($desired_colour, $desired_alpha, $background_colour: white) {
  $r3: red($desired_colour);
  $g3: green($desired_colour);
  $b3: blue($desired_colour);

  $r2: red($background_colour);
  $g2: green($background_colour);
  $b2: blue($background_colour);

  // r1 = (r3 - r2 + r2 * a1) / a1
  $r1: ( $r3 - $r2 + ($r2 * $desired_alpha) ) / $desired_alpha;
  $g1: ( $g3 - $g2 + ($g2 * $desired_alpha) ) / $desired_alpha;
  $b1: ( $b3 - $b2 + ($b2 * $desired_alpha) ) / $desired_alpha;

  background-color: $desired_colour;
  background-color: rgba($r1, $g1, $b1, $desired_alpha);
}

Comment: I adopted and made a SCSS version mixin.
Find the demo and code here: https://codepen.io/Grienauer/pen/Grogdx

Comment: @Grienauer I did the exact same, didn't realize you already shared it! My only difference is that I defaulted the background color to white

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to Phrogz's and ephemer's answers, I wrote a SCSS function to compute the best equivalent RGBA color.

You call it with the desired color and the existing background and it will compute the best (meaning most transparent) equivalent RGBA color that gives the desired result within ±1/256 of each RGB component (due to rounding errors):

```
@function alphaize($desired-color, $background-color) {

    $r1: red($background-color);
    $g1: green($background-color);
    $b1: blue($background-color);

    $r2: red($desired-color);
    $g2: green($desired-color);
    $b2: blue($desired-color);

    $alpha: 0;
    $r: -1;
    $g: -1;
    $b: -1;

    @while $alpha < 1 and ($r < 0 or $g < 0 or $b < 0
                           or $r > 255 or $g > 255 or $b > 255) {
        $alpha: $alpha + 1/256;
        $inv: 1 / $alpha;
        $r: $r2 * $inv + $r1 * (1 - $inv);
        $g: $g2 * $inv + $g1 * (1 - $inv);
        $b: $b2 * $inv + $b1 * (1 - $inv);
    }

    @return rgba($r, $g, $b, $alpha);
}
```

I just tested it against a number of combinations (all the Bootswatch themes) and it works well, both for dark-on-light and light-on-dark results.

Comment: FYI, this function exists in Stylus as `transparentify()`: http://stylus-lang.com/docs/bifs.html#transparentifytop-bottom-alpha

... which I discovered after porting this manually to Stylus ...

Answer (score 6):

From @Phrogz' answer:

```
r3 = r2 + (r1-r2)*a1
g3 = g2 + (g1-g2)*a1
b3 = b2 + (b1-b2)*a1
```

So:

```
r3 - r2 = (r1-r2)*a1
g3 - g2 = (g1-g2)*a1
b3 - b2 = (b1-b2)*a1
```

So:

```
r1 = (r3 - r2) / a1 + r2
g1 = (g3 - g2) / a1 + g2
b1 = (b3 - b2) / a1 + b2
```

Note you can pick any value of `a1`, and this will find the corresponding values of `r1`, `g1`, and `b1` required. For example, picking an alpha of 1 tells you that you need RGB1 = RGB3, but picking an alpha of 0 gives no solution (obviously).

Answer (score 2):

The most practical solution I found so far: just measure the resulting color with a color picker tool and then use the measured color for overlay. This method gives a perfect color match.

I've tried using different mixins but due to rounding error, I was still able to see the difference with a naked eye

Comment: The OP probably wanted a way to make the determination dynamically, but that wasn't specifically stated, and your answer does give a good hack for static color/alpha selections.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @Tobia's answer and allow for specifying the opacity more like transparentify:

```
@function rgbaMorph($desired-color, $background-color: rgb(255,255,255), $desired-alpha: 0) {

    $r1: red($desired-color);
    $g1: green($desired-color);
    $b1: blue($desired-color);

    $r2: red($background-color);
    $g2: green($background-color);
    $b2: blue($background-color);

    $r: -1;
    $g: -1;
    $b: -1;

    @if ($desired-alpha != 0) {
        $r: ( $r1 - $r2 + ($r2 * $desired-alpha) ) / $desired-alpha;
        $g: ( $g1 - $g2 + ($g2 * $desired-alpha) ) / $desired-alpha;
        $b: ( $b1 - $b2 + ($b2 * $desired-alpha) ) / $desired-alpha;
    }

    @if (($desired-alpha == 0) or ($r < 0 or $g < 0 or $b < 0
                           or $r > 255 or $g > 255 or $b > 255)) {
        //if alpha not attainable, this will find lowest alpha that is

        $alpha: $desired-alpha;
        @while $alpha < 1 and ($r < 0 or $g < 0 or $b < 0
                           or $r > 255 or $g > 255 or $b > 255) {
            $alpha: $alpha + 1/256;
            $inv: 1 / $alpha;
            $r: $r1 * $inv + $r2 * (1 - $inv);
            $g: $g1 * $inv + $g2 * (1 - $inv);
            $b: $b1 * $inv + $b2 * (1 - $inv);
        }
        @debug "Color not attainable at opacity using alpha: " $alpha " instead of: " $desired-alpha;

        $desired-alpha: $alpha;
    }

    @return rgba($r, $g, $b, $desired-alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a util that I can use from JSS to help me make a color transparent. It uses utility methods from material-ui which can be found [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/79e68968b8433a70cd739485087c4e1191bb9bd0/packages/material-ui/src/styles/colorManipulator.js.).
Here is the code for my utility class (in Typescript). Note that it is not possible to make some colors transparent while keeping their color the same as the target color.
Excuse my lack of codepen or runnable code. I hope someone finds this and gets some use out of it!

```js
import {
  decomposeColor,
  recomposeColor,
  ColorObject,
} from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';

/**
 * Take a non transparent color and create a transparent color that looks identical visually.
 * Using formula from this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228548/finding-equivalent-color-with-opacity
 * Assuming a white background
 * @param origColor The color you want to match.
 * @param value Transparency value between 0 and 1. Cannot be too low because it is mathematically not possible (usually <0.2 but depends on the color)
 */
export const makeTransparent = (origColor: string, value: number): string => {
  const origColorObj: ColorObject = decomposeColor(origColor);

  if (value >= 1 || value <= 0)
    throw new Error('makeTransparent: invalid value provided');

  if (origColorObj.values[3] != null && origColorObj.values[3] !== 1)
    throw new Error('makeTransparent: origColor cannot be transparent');

  const newColorObj: ColorObject = {
    type: 'rgba',
    values: [0, 0, 0, value],
  };

  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    const rgbNum: number = (255 * value + origColorObj.values[i] - 255) / value;

    if (rgbNum < 0 || rgbNum > 255)
      throw new Error('makeTransparent: Transparency value too low');

    newColorObj.values[i] = rgbNum;
  }

  return recomposeColor(newColorObj);
};
```