# Layered opaque element together make new color

Tags: css, svg

I have a design:

[image]

I want to have 2 svg polygons that overlap. Is it possible to have polygon 2, when overlapping other elements, creates a darker color and while overlapping white creates the same color as the non-opaque elements?

[image]

**UPDATE**

The markup is irrelevant because I'm just interested in the color values. I want to know the color value with an opacity value (alpha) that matches `rgb(0, 92, 150)` when the background color is white.

```
body {
  background: white;
}

.container {
  background: rgb(0, 92, 150);
}

.polygon-1 {
  fill: rgb(0, 92, 150);
}

.polygon-2 {
  fill: [a color value that has an alpha that, when it's over white, creates the same color as rgb(0, 92, 150) and creates the darker color effect when it overlays rgb(0, 92, 150)];
}
```

I guess [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-to-rgba-over-white) is essentially the same as mine.

According to the JS solution provided in that question, it takes the lowest number of the rgb to calculate the alpha. In my case, it's 0. The generated `rgba` value is `rgba(0, 92, 150, 1)` (no opacity). Does this mean that that particular color cannot create the desired effect?

```
var min, a = (255 - (min = Math.min(r, g, b))) / 255;
```

In my case, `Math.min(0, 92, 150)` is `0`, `(255 - 0) / 255` is 1, so my alpha value turns out to be 1. I need it to be less than 1 (at least a little bit).

**UPDATE 2**

To further question downvotes, here is a [crude codepen](https://codepen.io/grantholle/pen/QPzmMj) to illustrate my point.

Comment: I have found similar questions after more digging. Not sure why this is getting downvoted when it's essentially the same question as:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-to-rgba-over-white and 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12228548/finding-equivalent-color-with-opacity

Comment: Update your code. can you share one screenshot with expected output?

Comment: @Saravana good question, I've expanded my original question to add more details about my expectation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:
I'm adding a third shape: a `rect` instead of the blue `.container` and I'm using `<clipPath>` to clip between the polygons. In the example I'm filling red but you may fill it with whatever you like.

I hope it helps.

```css
.outer-container {
  background: white;
  padding-top: 10rem;
}

.outer-container * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  
  width: 300px;
  padding: 4px 10px 25px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5rem;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.polygon-1,
.polygon-2,
.polygon-3{
   fill: rgb(0, 92, 150);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
  <div class="container">
    <h3>Education</h3>
    
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 60">
      <defs>
      <polygon id="p1" points="10,40 72,0 85,25 15,53"></polygon>
      <polygon id="p2" points="10,10 90,25 80,55 25,53"></polygon> 
      <rect id="p3" y="40%" width="100%" height="60%" />
        
       <clipPath id="clip1">
       <use xlink:href="#p1"></use>    
       </clipPath>
       <clipPath id="clip2">
       <use xlink:href="#p3"></use>
       </clipPath>
      </defs>
      <use xlink:href="#p1" class="polygon-1"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#p2" class="polygon-2"></use>
      <use xlink:href="#p3" class="polygon-3"></use>
      <g fill="red">
      <use xlink:href="#p2" clip-path="url(#clip1)"  /> 
      <use xlink:href="#p2" clip-path="url(#clip2)"  />
      </g>
      
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's clever. I'm really hoping for a color solution but this is definitely a fall back if nothing else can be found. Thanks for this direction!