# Even/Odd table row styles with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

Here is an HTML/jquery code from w3s website.
If you try it at: [Try It W3S](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_sel_odd)
You will see the problem. odd rows have different opacity than even rows, this is ok,
but I want the text color(or brightness) to remain the same. How to do it?
I have tried it by setting: `$("tr td").css("opacity","1.0");` but it didn't help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("tr").css("background-color", "yellow").css("opacity","1.0");

 $("tr:odd").css("opacity","0.5");
 $("tr td").css("opacity","1.0");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Welcome to My Web Page</h1>

<table border="1">
<tr>
  <th>Company</th>
  <th>Country</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
<td>Germany</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Berglunds snabbkцp</td>
<td>Sweden</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
<td>Mexico</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Ernst Handel</td>
<td>Austria</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Island Trading</td>
<td>UK</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: Seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uYSJ8/. The text color is the same but since you change the opacity it looks lighter.

Comment: @j08691 The thing is that I don't want the text to be lighter. I want keep it the same as in the even rows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the text-color *stays the same*. However, `opacity` always affects the whole element (backgrounds,borders,text-colors) and *all it's descendants*. If you want to have transparent background only, you have to use hsla or rgba colors for the background which introduce a "transparency" channel which only affects the background of that single element:

```
// all you need is:
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("tr:even").css("background-color","rgb(255,255,0)");
    // rgba equivalent for yellow with 50% opacity
    $("tr:odd").css("background-color","rgba(255,255,0,0.5)");
});
```

[Your modified Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uYSJ8/1/)

EDIT: alternatively [this question about converting RGB to RGBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-rgba/6672545#comment24235638_6672545) is very interesting and touches the topic about opacity altering the visual representation of a color.

However you don't need javascript at all to achieve that effect, a [simple css declaration will do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17091744/1047823).

Answer (score 3):

You can do this quite simply with CSS3:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help,

```
    <script>
    $( "tr:even" ).css( "background-color", "#A9D6F5" );
    $( "tr:odd" ).css( "background-color", "#ACE6CB" )
    </script>
```