# HEX color to equivalent RGBa, allowing for transparency

Tags: css, hex, rgba

For a given hex color code, how can I convert it to an `rbga` color code where a=0.97 and the rendered color is the same as the initial hex color?

In other words, if I have `#ccc`, I need an `rgba` equivalent which stills renders the same color as `#ccc` but has transparency.

Comment: The perceived color of a translucent element will depend on what it is atop: a color, multiple colors, an image, etc. If the background color of the element beneath it is constant, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672374/convert-rgb-rgba?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

To convert to rgba, you have to do this:

1- Divide your hex color code to 3 parts

```
cccccc => cc(r)|cc(g)|cc(b)
```

2- For each part, convert it to int by using parseInt

```
r = parseInt("cc", 16)
g = parseInt("cc", 16)
b = parseInt("cc", 16)
```

3- Add desired alpha value to your final rgba code