# Inset box-shadow beneath content

Tags: z-index, css

I don't understand why, but an inset box shadow is beneath my content.

Here's an example:

```css
div {
   box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px black;
   height:300px;
   color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>
   a
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MAckM/

You see the `a` is on top of the box shadow.

How can I get the box shadow to be on top of the `a`?

Comment: I already used this olution works great, but additionaly inportant thing is z-index of this div:before.
Don't forget to use it when You have trouble to cover full content.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to make a new element inside the div, with absolute positioning and height and width of 100%, then give that element the box shadow.

```css
div {
    height: 300px;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

div > div {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div></div>
    Sample text
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can use a pseudo-element:

```css
div {
    height: 300px;
    color: red;
    position: relative;
}

div:before {
    content: '';
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px black;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}​
```

```html
<div>
    Sample text
</div>​
```

Comment: In modern browsers (incl. IE9+), generated content (`:before`, `:after`) can be used instead of a real element. (IE8 does support generated content too, but has a bug preventing generated content to be above real content, and of course does not support CSS box shadow itself.)

Comment: @MaratTanalin Absolutely right. And its a much more beautiful solution, too. Updated the answer.

Comment: Either answer is fine by me, but I have a problem. When I have another `div` inside the central `div` the shadow element or pseudo class lays on top of the inner `div`. If I add a z-index to the inner div, then it goes on top of the box-shadow. Try to click on the link in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MAckM/5/

Comment: Another way would be to create 4 separate elements with linear gradients and position them on the edges, to mimic what a box shadow would look like. But if IE support is what you're looking for, I'm afraid that won't do either.

Comment: Yes, I thought that would be other way :(. Thanks

Comment: Apparently, for the containers that have scrollable content, it's better to use the empty `div`, as `:before` will make the shadow scroll with the content.

Comment: For me, the div solution also make the shadow scrolling. Plus, I lose my parent padding to adjust content.

Comment: @fncombo can you please review this question about your solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49652744/inset-box-shadow-beneath-content-scroll-fix

Comment: Should really be an :after if you want it to appear above the other div (sibling) contents as dom elements are stacked on top by default. Of course you could apply a z-index to the before but seems cleaner as an :after

Comment: I would suggest adding ``pointer-events: none;`` as in Michael Plotke's answer.

Answer (score 7):

This answer offers the most straightforward solution via a minimal example and addresses the issue of scrolling.

Unfortunately there is no way to avoid an extra wrapping `div` (due to [`box-shadow` layering](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#shadow-layers)).

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 9px 3px yellow;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.items {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="items">
    <div class="item">One</div>
    <div class="item">Two</div>
    <div class="item">Three</div>
    <div class="item">Four</div>
    <div class="item">Five</div>
    <div class="item">Six</div>
    <div class="item">Seven</div>
    <div class="item">Eight</div>
    <div class="item">Nine</div>
    <div class="item">Ten</div>
    <div class="item">Eleven</div>
    <div class="item">Twelve</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Plus 1 for the pointer-events: none; That's what I needed.